# Multiple Conditions in shell script

Tags: macos, mac, bash, unix, shell

Im stuck in giving two conditions in my script. I can read two things -

1. What is the NEAREST SERVER
2. If it is MacBook or Anything Else

and then use defaults write command to modify the plist file.

How can I add a line that cross checks both things - MODEL & SERVER and then write the file accordingly?

```
#!/bin/sh
# Get the logfile for this machine
dslog="/tmp/DSNetworkRepository/Logs/$(ioreg -l | grep IOPlatformSerialNumber | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d \" -f 2).log"

NEARESTSERVER=$(awk 'gsub(/.*server=|port=.*/,"")' $dslog | tail -1)


# get machine model
MACHINE_MODEL=`/usr/sbin/ioreg -c IOPlatformExpertDevice | grep "model" | awk -F\" '{ print $4 }'`

MacBook=`/usr/sbin/ioreg -c IOPlatformExpertDevice | grep "model" | cut -c21-27`


# Check if the Model is MacBook or Desktop & connected to which Booster and write the plist file accordingly

if [[ "${MACHINE_MODEL}" == "MacBook" && $NEARESTSERVER == 'SRV-DELHI.xaas.com']]
then
  defaults write /Library/com.myorg.repo ConnectionNumber -string One

elif [[ "${MACHINE_MODEL}" != "MacBook" && $NEARESTSERVER == 'SRV-DELHI.xaas.com']]
then
  defaults write /Library/com.myorg.repo ConnectionNumber -string Two

fi

# Check if the Model is MacBook or Desktop & connected to which Booster and write the plist file accordingly
if [[ "${MACHINE_MODEL}" == "MacBook" && $NEARESTSERVER == 'SRV-MUMBAI.xaas.com']] 
then
  defaults write /Library/com.myorg.repo ConnectionNumber -string Three

elif [[ "${MACHINE_MODEL}" != "MacBook" && $NEARESTSERVER == 'SRV-MUMBAI.xaas.com']] 
then
  defaults write /Library/com.myorg.repo ConnectionNumber -string Four

fi

exit 0
```

Comment: Er - what is the question? You have a script that contains a few conditionals, and those seem to be well-formed at first glance. I don't have Mac, so I can't check ...

Comment: I just need to know how do you put two if in a script? I mean, I need to check what MACHINE_MODEL is and what the NEARESTSERVER is, and take action accordingly.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't understand. You already check MACHINE_MODEL and NEARESTSERVER, and you do take action accordingly. Of course, the script could be simplified somewhat (by cascading the if's), but it basically seems to do what you ask. (I can't run it to check)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it right you want to understand how to make this more short and structured in `Shell` language.

I would do something like this:

```
set -A strings \
    One \
    Two \
    Three \
    Four
# You should swap Three and Four so it's easy to fit the logic.
counter=0
for i in \
    "[ \"$NEARESTSERVER\" == 'SRV-MUMBAI.xaas.com' ]" \
    "[ \"$MACHINE_MODEL\" = 'MacBook' ]" ; do
    eval "$i && counter=\"$(($counter + (! $? + 1)))\""
done
defaults write /Library/com.myorg.repo ConnectionNumber -string ${strings[$counter]}
```

You should test and adjust this a bit because I could have missed something. I know no other way to make this better (except for using namespaces instead of lists).